# Blueimp get uploaded filename

Tags: jquery, file-upload, blueimp

I need to recover the name or the url of my uploaded file:

```
<script>
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({

        complete: function (e, data) {
            $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
              alert(file.name);
            });
        }
        });
</script>
```

but in the alert i have in console :

> jquery.js:358 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of
>   undefined

how solve it ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
$('#fileupload').on("fileuploaddone", function (e, data) {
    $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
        alert(file.name);
    });
});
```

Also other than *fileuploaddone* "events" can be used. See:

https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options#callback-options

Answer (score 1):

most probably you do not return the name of the files from the server. The response should be of the form

```
{ 
  files:
    [
      {
        url: "http://url.to/file/or/page",
        thumbnail_url: "http://url.to/thumnail.jpg ",
        name: "thumb2.jpg",
        type: "image/jpeg",
        size: 46353,
        delete_url: "http://url.to/delete /file/",
        delete_type: "DELETE"
      }
    ]
}
```

Have a look at the following url to see the response 
https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/JSON-Response

make sure than in the json that you return, you return the name property and that you return the whole json message like the format above.

let me know if this helped

Comment: The code is used for client side. What code and language did you use for server side?